# Moving Labels and Pictures

Tags: vb.net

What's the code to move pictures left to right using x and y axis instead of hide and show?

Comment: Not enough detail provided. Tags are VB and C++? 0.o

Comment: What language and UI framework?

Comment: c++ language im using the program visual basic.  Im trying to figure out how to move an object in debug mode using a timber box.  Whats the smoothest way anyone know?

Comment: What language is the program being written in?  What is the source code file's extension?  .VB  .C  .CPP?

Comment: file extensions is vb.
the language the program is being written in is c++.

Comment: I think you don't know what C++ is.  What does the code look like?

Comment: its kind of like   picblah.right = 5  thats the one im looking for because its smoother the one i have been using was 
If countseconds = 1 then
picblah.visible = false
picblah1.visible = true
Else If

Comment: if the "if countseconds = 1" uses a single = and not a double ==, then it's probably visual basic, which agrees with what I would guess based on the file extension.  Now, do you have any idea what UI framework you're using?  It makes a difference if you're in VB6 versus a later, .Net version.

Comment: Since the file extension is `vb`, he's using VB .Net.

Comment: Guess that's what I get for not being a VB programmer.  What's the extension for VB6 files?

Comment: `.frm`, `.ctl`, `'cls`, or `.bas`, for forms, user controls, classes, or modules, respectively.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably using Visual Basic .NET 2008.

Please be aware that it has nothing to do with C++.

If you have a PictureBox named `MyPicture`, you can move it by changing the `Top` and `Left` properties.

If you want to animate the picture (for example, if you want to gradually move it across the screen), you'll need to use the Timer component, and change the `Left` property in the Timer's `Tick` event.